# how do I append a $ symbol at beginning label

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. Want to append a '$' symbol at the beginning of the label.

Here is my code. Thank you for looking.

```
<input id="field1" type="text" />
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#field1').keydown(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#output').append("$").text($('#field1').val() / 100).append(".00");
            }, 50);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Output for the code above if users types 3000 then the output will be 30.00. **But I want output to be $30.00**

I could do this

```
$<div id="output"></div>
```

but it doesn't align well.

Comment: `$('#output').prepend("$")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `text()` is overwriting the `$` which you append first. Instead, `prepend` the `$` last:

```
$('#output').text($('#field1').val() / 100).append(".00").prepend("$");
```

Comment: got it to work using prepend("$"). Thank you.  A related question...want to save this value to the database by copying it to another field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the HTML special character for $?

```
.prepend("&#36;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply this?

check out the mind-blowingly mind-blowing demo.

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/55948aab271b02621b5f6f8ff9160f08)

```
$('#output').text('$'+ ($('#field1').val() / 100) + '.00');
```

Comment: Because the string concatenation will mess up the division, and you've also got mismatched brackets.

Comment: they're parentheses, and my bad, bro... I missed a single character. check my edit.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use functions such as `append` and `prepend` in this use case...

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Wouldn't you agree that the usage of `prepend`, etc method is overkill? Also, while *technically* a legal HTML string, this contains no elements. using this to make simple textual changes is wholly inefficient.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree in this case.

Comment: Todd. I tried your code and get this when I start typing: **$NaN.00**  I'll just use Rory McCrossan's code for now. Thank you  everyone!

Comment: Am an idiot. Both answers work! Todd's code is much easier to read. Thank you everyone!